# Can hypohydrosis (inability to sweat) be caused be excess adrenaline?

Tags: medical-science

A BBC TV interview with Prince Andrew (of the British royal family) is described below:

> On claims he was sweating, he said: "I have a peculiar medical condition which is that I don't sweat or I didn't sweat at the time," he said, blaming it on "an overdose of adrenaline in the Falklands War".
>
> He said he had only started to be able to sweat again "in the recent past".

[Prince Andrew 'categorically' denies sex claims](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-50446065), BBC News, 17 November 2019

The medical disorder whereby a person is unable to sweat is named 'anhidrosis' or '[hypohidrosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypohidrosis)'. Can this disorder be caused by "an overdose of adrenalin"?

Comment: Hard to Prove as its such a rare condition and can sometimes happen for seemingly no reason called idiopathic hypohidrosis

Comment: This might be better served in Medical Sciences, they can probably speak on it better than we can.

Comment: It seems rather improbable the effect was direct like that. Hypohidrosis is linked to excess acetylcholine (rather than adrenaline). It may be caused by a number of drugs that the palace might not want to disclose the prince was taking, including (tricyclic) antidepressants. https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18217788?dopt=Abstract The number of muscarinic antagonists (which would cause the same effect) is rather large though and includes many other drugs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscarinic_antagonist

Comment: Something like (treatment for) overactive bladder might be equally embarrassing for the palace to disclose https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6160033 The latter also correlates with higher stress levels, including with PTSD https://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5116264

Comment: The Atlantic actually offers a direct link "People who become accustomed to working in high-pressure situations, such as on a battlefield, may develop a tolerance to the effects of adrenaline surges. A general sense of imperturbability could hypothetically translate into other high-pressure situations. After a deeply traumatic event, everything else can feel low-stakes. Or, at an extreme end, this is the phenomenon described in people known as sociopaths: A tendency to not worry or panic becomes an outright inability to do so." I doubt it myself, but it's probably a better claim to challenge.

Comment: The Sun quoted two MDs/experts (unusual for them eh?) who both disagree with The Atlantic style direct link https://www.thesun.co.uk/fabulous/10367149/prince-andrew-claim-medical-condition-sweating-rare-real/ It may be one of the few case in which the tabloids have better info than more "serious" media. (Nothing like celebrities to motivate them to do go work eh?) "In fact, high levels of adrenaline can lead to increased sweating, not less. There is no evidence that trauma leads to anhidrosis."

Comment: Science Media Center found one expert who agrees with The Atlantic version though (on habituation) https://www.sciencemediacentre.org/expert-reaction-to-prince-andrews-claims-regarding-his-ability-to-sweat/ But the only evidence is from horses. Oddly none of the experts mention the possibility that the prince was taking some drug, which is also known cause of hypohidrosis (in humans).

Comment: And the whole thing is probably nonsense since there's apparently a video of him sweating around that time. https://nypost.com/2019/11/17/video-photos-show-sweaty-prince-andrew-in-public-with-sexy-women-report/

Comment: Also https://twitter.com/DrMatthewSweet/status/1196080908824203265/photo/1

Comment: @Fizz You should turn that into an answer.  :)

Answer (score 4):

While I can't say he's lying, there's no evidence that acquired anhydrosis is related to chronic stress (or chronic elevations of adrenaline/norepinephrine.)

Acquired anhydrosis is uncommon but not rare, and is usually caused by diseases that also happen to attack either the nervous system or the sweat glands themselves. It can also be caused by injuries to the skin (burns/heatstroke.)

Idiopathic acquired anhydrosis (anhydrosis with an unknown cause) is a very rare disease which is reportable in the medical literature. None of the reports I've seen address chronic stress.

Just going on common sense, if his claim were true, we'd see a higher incidence here in the US in combat veterans. No such study exists.

Most likely he was sweating from the usual causes: he was nervous or hot.

<sub>[Acquired Idiopathic Generalized Anhidrosis](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4533576/)</sub>
<sub>[Acquired idiopathic generalized anhidrosis: a distinctive clinical syndrome](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00314488)</sub>
<sub>[Acquired idiopathic generalized anhidrosis: clinical manifestations and histochemical studies](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022510X9500125L)</sub>
<sub>[Skin sympathetic nerve activity in acquired idiopathic generalized anhidrosis](https://n.neurology.org/content/43/6/1137.short)</sub>
<sub>Acquired idiopathic generalized anhidrosis in combat veterans</sub>